# Deploy Dashboards and Reports using Migration Tool

Tags: migration-tool

I can't find a way to deploy Reports and Dashboards to a new organization. It's complaining it can't find the reports folder. And there's a very unhelpful error with the folder:

```
reports/Public_Reports-meta.xml -- Error: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 376420038-11797 (1290830229)
reports/Public_Reports/New_Total_Revenue_per_Client2.report -- Error: Cannot find folder:Public_Reports
```

Is there a particular configuration I need to set the folder so that the migration tool can deploy it?
Here's my Public_Reports-meta.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReportFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <folderShares>
        <accessLevel>View</accessLevel>
        <sharedTo>AllInternalUsers</sharedTo>
        <sharedToType>Organization</sharedToType>
    </folderShares>
    <name>Public Reports</name>
</ReportFolder>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

> What i have previously observed is that usually if source org has folder sharing enabled and destination does not have ,we get this unexpected error .Certainly something sfdc needs to take care
>
> Quick fix for the same is to check the folder sharing in destination if source has this and then try deploying the same .

Comment: btw: Not sure if this setting exists anymore in recently-created instances - I couldn't find it in mine

Answer (score 0):

Exactly I too encountered the same problem when i was trying to deploy Email template, so what i did was i created one folder with the same name and then deployed it, It worked just try out.

Comment: The cause of the issue was not able to move folders .SO manually creating folders is always something one can do but the problem statement is why folders one was not able to migrate ?Even folders metadata API is exposed and hence ideally even folders can be moved from one org to another without issues unless user dont exist in the destination instance